# How to get table comments via SQL in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I've tried :

```
select * from user_tab_comments;
```

and it returns me 3 columns "TABLE_NAME", "TABLE_TYPE", and "COMMENTS", but the "TABLE_NAME" column is like "encrypted", I need clear table names :

```
TABLE_NAME                      TABLE_TYPE  COMMENTS

BIN$IN1vjtqhTEKcWfn9PshHYg==$0  TABLE       Résultat d'intégration d'une photo numérisée
BIN$PUwG3lb3QoazOc4QaC1sjw==$0  TABLE       Motif de fin d'agrément de maître de stage
```

When I use `select * from user_tables;` TABLE_NAME is not "encrypted".

Comment: May be you need to set some DBA parameters. It works here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fbc1c/1

Comment: `BIN$IN1vjtqhTEKcWfn9PshHYg==$0` is an object in the recyclebin (a dropped table, sequence, view...). You can safely ignore them. More details in the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/tables011.htm#ADMIN11679

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Since 10g Oracle doesn't immediately drop tables when we issue a DROP TABLE statement.  Instead it renames them like this `BIN$IN1vjtqhTEKcWfn9PshHYg==$0` and puts them in the recycle bin.  This allows us to recover tables we didn't mean to drop.  [Find out more](http://www.orafaq.com/node/968).

Tables in the recycle bin are still tables, so they show up in ALL_TABLES and similar views.  So if you only want to see comments relating only to live (non-dropped) tables you need to filter by table name:

```
select * from all_tab_comments
where substr(table_name,1,4) != 'BIN$'
/
```

---

> "I can't believe there isn't a flag column so you could do and is_recycled = 0 or something. "

You're right, it would be incredible. So I checked the documentation it turns out Oracle 10g added a column called DROPPED to the USER_/ALL_/DBA_TABLES views.

```
select tc.* 
from all_tab_comments tc
     join all_tables t
     on tc.owner = t.owner
     and tc.table_name = t.table_name
where t.dropped = 'NO'
/
```

Check out [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-6823CD28-0681-468E-950B-966C6F71325D.htm#REFRN20286). Obviously the need to join to the ALL_TABLES view requires more typing than filtering on the name, so depending on our need it might just be easier to keep the original WHERE clause.

Comment: I can't believe there isn't a flag column so you could do `and is_recycled = 0` or something. Or is there?

Comment: @AndrewSpencer:  ...sort of...you could specifically exclude tables in the recycle bin: `select * from all_tab_comments atc where not exists (select null from dba_recyclebin drb where drb.owner = atc.owner and drb.object_name = atc.table_name);`

Comment: @AndrewSpencer - rather belatedly I checked the documentation and lo! there is such a flag. We learn something every day :)

Comment: @APC Nice. Of course when I wrote, "I can't believe," what I really meant was "I could only too well believe." Otherwise ... presumably ... I would have taken 2 minutes to read the documentation myself ... I hope.

Comment: @APC:  Even better!  Didn't think to check there.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT t.table_name,t.comments FROM USER_TAB_COMMENTS t WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'SS_DEPT';