# Where to store table version

Tags: oracle

Where's the best place to store the version of a table in Oracle? Is it possible to store the version in the table itself, e. g. similar to the comment assigned to a table?

Comment: Depends too much on the deployment methods/tooling used, but personally I've never seen that information stored as part of the table itself.

Comment: What do you mean by version of table? Are you maintaining multiple version of same table in the database? Or is it just one and you just want to add some meta information to it?

Comment: So there's no way to store some meta-information in the data dictionary?

Comment: @Gurwinder Singh When we roll out a new release to customers, we have to upgrade database automatically. So some kind of meta information would be helpful for decisions about which script needs to be applied. Scanning the table structure and basing decisions on that is too heuristic.

Comment: @Roland Have a look at [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/). It allows you to migrate database to new versions. It will create a separate table in the database in which it keeps track of the migrations that have been executed. It doesn't do  that per object, but based on migration scripts. Every script that needs to be executed will be executed in the right order.

Comment: @GolezTrol Thanks! That would be a great alternative

Comment: You're welcome. I've added an answer with a bit more explanation and motivation about Flyway, and about Red Gate source control (another tool I've used), and the migration process in general. I don't have shares in either, but I do have a very large, ever changing database, and the migration issues we had over the years finally seem to be gone now. :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can store that information in Oracle, except maybe in a comment on the table, but that would be error prone.

But personally I think you shouldn't want to keep track of versions of tables. After all, to get from a version 1 to a version 2, you may need to modify data as well, or other objects like triggers and procedures that use to new version of the table.

So in a way, it's better to version the entire database, so you can 'combine' multiple changes in one atomic version number.

There are different approaches to this, and different tools that can help you with that. I think Oracle even has some built-in feature, but with Oracle, that means that you will be charged gold bars if you use it, so I won't get into that, and just describe the two that I *have* tried:

**Been there, done that: saving schema structure in Git**

At some point we wanted to save our database changes in GitHub, where our other source is too.

We've been using [Red Gate Source Control for Oracle](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/index) (and Schema Compare, a similar tool), and have been looking into other similar tools as well. These tools use version control like Git to keep the latest structure of the database, and it can help you get your changes from your development database to scripts folder or VCS, and it can generate migration scripts for you.

Personally I'm not a big fan, because those tools and scripts focus only on the structure of the database (like you would with versioning individual tables). You'd still need to know how to get from version 1 to version 2, and sometimes only adding a column isn't enough; you need to migrate your data too. This isn't covered properly by tools like this.

In addition, I thought they were overall quite expensive for the work that they do, they don't work as easy as promised on the box, and you'd need different tools for different databases.

**Working with migrations**

A better solution would be to have migration script. You just make a script to get your database from version 1 to version 2, and another script to get it from version 2 to version 3. These migrations can be about table structure, object modifications, or even just data, it doesn't matter. All you need to do is remember which script was executed last, and execute all versions after that.

Executing migrations can be done by hand, or you can simply script it. But there are tools for this as well. One of them is [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/), a free tool (paid pro support should you need it) that does exactly this. You can feed it SQL scripts from a folder, which are sorted and executed in order. Each script is a 'version'. Meta data about the process is stored in a separate table in your database. The whole process is described in [more detail on Flyway's website](https://flywaydb.org/getstarted/how).

The advantage of this tool is that it's really simple and flexible, because you just write the migration scripts yourself. All the tool does is execute them and keep track of it. And it can do it for all kinds of databases, so you can introduce the same flow for each database you have.

Comment: Exactly what I was searching for and more. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

One way is to define a comment on the table:

```
comment on table your_table is 'some comment';
```

Then you can read that meta information using `all_tab_comments` table.

See

- [How to get table comments via SQL in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16567129/how-to-get-table-comments-via-sql-in-oracle)

For further reading, see:

- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4009.htm

Comment: Thanks, I know that one, and is the only option I could think of, hence the question here. But that would be abusing the comments. I was looking for a more dedicated approach with meta information, regardless if it's a comment or not. Nontheless with custom tags in the comments it might suffice.